# Plot Function Performance (Computational Speed) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, datetime

I'd like to compare two functions for solving a specific task (converting from `string` to `datetime` structure). What would be an effective way to measure the speed of these functions to be accessed for plotting?

***Note:** I'd really like to store the computational speeds at various data sizes, perhaps in a pandas dataframe. To this aim, `perfplot` does not suffice as a solution.*

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Create sample data
some_date = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
s = [(some_date+datetime.timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for i in range(10**3)]

# multiply the series by itself (so that it repeats itself)
s *= 10**2
s = pd.Series(s)

# First function
def f1(s):
    """
    converts from string format to dt format
    """
    return pd.to_datetime(s)

# Second function
def f2(s):
    """
    converts from string format to dt format
    """
    return pd.to_datetime(s)
```

Comment: There are several benchmark packages, [this](https://pypi.org/project/simple-benchmark/) for example.

Comment: That's very helpful @QuangHoang. If you'd format as a response, I'd happily accept as an answer.